# tf.reshape dimensions are not matching the output of tf.decode_raw

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(cat_in_snow)
height, width, channels = img.shape
print (height, width, channels)
```

> > output of above code snippet is [213 320 3]

```
raw_image_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('images.tfrecords')
# Create a dictionary describing the features.
image_feature_description = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
}

def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)

parsed_image_dataset = raw_image_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)

for image_features in parsed_image_dataset:  
  print(image_features['image_raw'])
  image_raw = image_features['image_raw'].numpy()
  dec_img = tf.io.decode_raw(image_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  img = tf.reshape(dec_img,[213 ,320, 3])
```

> > InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 17858 values, but the requested shape has 204480 [Op:Reshape]

The above file contains the same image as used in opencv read but decode_raw function is giving different output. can someone help me how to fix this ?

Comment: how have you encoded the images in your tfrecords file?

Comment: yes. I passed the string of the image to the feature may where it was converted to bytelist

Comment: A Tensor must be one of the following types: int32, int64 for tf.reshape.

Comment: interesting. Why not uint8 ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

I found that if you save **image string** into tfrecords, you can use `tf.io.decode_raw' method.

```
image_data = matplotlib.image.imread(img_path)
# Convert image to string data
image_str = image_data.tostring()
```

But for me, I **read and store image data in terms of bytes**, so I use 'tf.image.decode_image' method instead.

```
with tf.compat.v1.gfile.FastGFile(img_path, 'rb') as fid:
                    image_data = fid.read()
```

Hope this answer helps you.